# How to get context from NativeScript modal opener through frame?

Tags: nativescript

I'm unable get showModal to pass context through a frame to the default page. Also, showingModally does not seem to fire when modal is loaded (I guess args from showingModally should pass context?).

I've tried the example provided on https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/modal-view under Custom Actionbar, because I need the modal to load within a frame. The modal opens and closes fine, but showingModally in the modal XML does not seem to run.

home/home-page.js

```
const modalView = "home/modal-root";

function openModal(args) {
  console.log('Opens modal');
  const mainpage = args.object.page;
  const context = "some context";
  mainpage.showModal(modalView, context, () => {
    console.log('Modal closed');
  }, true);
}
exports.openModal = openModal;
```

home/home-page.xml

```xml
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
    <Page.actionBar>
        <ActionBar title="Modal view Navigation" />
    </Page.actionBar>

    <GridLayout rows="auto, *">

        <Button text="Open modal" tap="openModal" textWrap="true" />

    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

home/modal-root.xml

```xml
<Frame defaultPage="home/modal-view-page" />
```

home/modal-view-page.js

```
function onShowingModally(args) {
    console.log("onShowingModally");
}
exports.onShowingModally = onShowingModally;

function onCloseModal(args) {
    args.object.closeModal();
}
exports.onCloseModal = onCloseModal;
```

home/modal-view-page.xml

```xml
<Page backgroundColor="green" showingModally="onShowingModally">
    <Page.actionBar>
        <ActionBar backgroundColor="red" title="Modal view" icon="">
        </ActionBar>
    </Page.actionBar>
    <StackLayout backgroundColor="lightGreen">
        <Label text="Modal view with ActionBar" style="text-align:center;" textWrap="true" />
        <Button text="Close Modal" tap="onCloseModal" />
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

I've added the example to https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=lFxTi4&v=9
with console logging.

Console show "Opens modal" on open and "Modal closed" on close as expected (from home/home-page.js), but "onShowingModally" (home/modal-view-page.js) nevers shows in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the docs need to be fixed. When you have the `Frame` being shown modally, the event will be called on the `Frame` not on the page within. If you are showing a simple view instead of `Frame`, then the event should be called on the view, basically whatever is the root view for your modal and in your example it's the `Frame`.

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=lFxTi4&v=11)